# jQuery slide from left + dim background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to dim the background while slide-opening the left menu to right.

Here is the [link](http://semia.coproductivity.com) and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/kq5vo508/).

At first run, when the dimmer code is commented out, it hides sliding to left and after the 2nd click its working okay. When the dimmer code is included, it doesn't remove the `class='dimmer'` and I can't click again.

Here is the jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
jQuery(".x-btn-navbar").click(function(){

    //if (jQuery('#dimmer').hasClass('dimmer')){
        //jQuery('#dimmer').removeClass('dimmer');
    //} else {
        //jQuery('#dimmer').addClass('dimmer');
    //}
    jQuery('.nav-animate').fadeIn(500);
    jQuery('.nav-animate nav').toggle('slide', {direction:'left'}, 500);

});
});
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: You want to dim when the menu is visible or it is hidden?

Comment: FWIW, `.toggleClass('dimmer')` could replace that entire `if()` statement.

Comment: @void after its clicked and before the menu is completely open

Comment: I didnt get you EHB. Please explain the patter a bit more.

Comment: thanks George, oh sorry @void I basically want to dim the background while the menu is opening. At the second the menu is open it has to be dimmed already.

Comment: Cool, let me give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, I guess...

Changes in **HTML**

```
<div class="x-navbar-wrap" style="z-index:999;">
    <div class="x-navbar x-navbar-fixed-left">
      <div class="x-navbar-inner">
        <div class="x-container max width">
<a data-target=".x-nav-wrap.mobile" class="x-btn-navbar" href="#">
  <span style="margin:-17px;font-size:20px;">MENU</span>
</a>
<!------- You didn't had these closing tags ---->
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS** changes

```
#dimmer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    jQuery('.nav-animate nav').hide('slide', {direction:'left'}, 500);
    jQuery(".x-btn-navbar").click(function(){
        jQuery('#dimmer').fadeIn(250, function(){
        jQuery('#dimmer').fadeOut(250);
        })
        jQuery('.nav-animate').fadeIn(500);
        jQuery('.nav-animate nav').toggle('slide', {direction:'left'}, 500);

    });
});
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq5vo508/4/)**

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! But I need to keep the dimmer until the user clicks again to close the menu. Sorry if I couldn't make it clear. I'm trying to achieve it with your code now.

Comment: Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Cool. Just keep in mind to do the proper modifications in HTML and CSS as well. Also please give `z-index:-1` to `#dimmer`.

Comment: Working like a charm, thanks for both! Didn't know the `.fadeToggle`. At first I wanted to use the animate. But seems this is simpler with fadeToggle, fadeIn, toggle etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71045/discussion-between-void-and-e-h-b).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you:

```
jQuery('.nav-animate nav').css({
    opacity: 0,
    left: -$('.nav-animate nav').outerWidth()
});
jQuery(".x-btn-navbar").click(function () {
    if (jQuery('#dimmer').hasClass('dimmer')) {
        jQuery('#dimmer').removeClass('dimmer');
        jQuery('.nav-animate nav').animate({
            opacity: 0,
            left: -$('.nav-animate nav').outerWidth()
        }, 500);
    } else {
        jQuery('#dimmer').addClass('dimmer');
        jQuery('.nav-animate nav').animate({
            opacity: 1,
            left: $('.x-btn-navbar').outerWidth()
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kq5vo508/2/**

Comment: Instead of addClass() and removeClass() can't you just call toggleClass()? But other than that I like your answer.

Comment: Thanks! Did you only change the script? Cause when I try the script it fails.

Comment: @E.H.B Did you remember to put the code in the document.ready function?

Comment: @E.H.B I changed some css. user void's answer is better explained

Answer (score 0):

i hope i got your question right, but from the link you attached it seems that you have a problem with the first click on the menu button and that later on confuse the dimmer status.

in your HTML you have the nav section

```
<section class="nav-animate">
    <nav style="height:auto;" class="x-nav-wrap mobile cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-push">
```

And your css sets `.nav-animate` to not be displayed, try removing that setting and instead set the inner nav tag to `display:none;`